# Performing Anova for all vars in R

Tags: r, anova

R has `aov-function` for anova. So if I want to perform it, i can write simple code:

```
df2=read.csv("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/222.csv",sep=";", dec=",")
fit=aov(x1 ~ Q7,data=df2)
summary(fit)
```

I can  perform 3 anova for each variables, if i three time write this code.
But how perform anova for  all three variables at once? I.E. not writing this for each `X`.

```
df2=

structure(list(Q7 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    x1 = c(13L, 31L, 17L, 27L, 24L, 21L, 34L, 28L, 13L, 25L, 
    12L, 16L, 26L, 27L, 20L), x2 = c(32L, 29L, 16L, 27L, 27L, 
    22L, 36L, 35L, 22L, 27L, 13L, 30L, 17L, 27L, 9L), x3 = c(29L, 
    13L, 18L, 25L, 19L, 21L, 24L, 22L, 30L, 30L, 14L, 28L, 19L, 
    11L, 13L)), .Names = c("Q7", "x1", "x2", "x3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reformulate()` to come up with the formulas to be used within aov` function.

```
lapply(names(df2[-1]),function(x)aov(reformulate("Q7",x),data=df2))
```

You can also add `summary` in the code above

Comment: Please explain to OP and future readers what your code does and output.